# Can't Save web design file - System cannot find specified file

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files

I am working in Windows 10 using WebPlus x8 app to update a client web site. When I attempt to Save changes, I get the following error.

**Failed to save site.
C:/Users/sally/Documents/~WEbPlus_sites/ABI/abitemplelorain.wpp
(MakeTempFileNameAPI)
The system cannot find the file specified.**

I can publish the site fine, but the app can't save the changes. So when I close it, I lose the changes I made. I am not a programmer or developer - just a web designer. I can't save files from Web Plus for any of my client's updates.

Is there a simple way to replace the temp file myself so that I can save the changes? I assume when I used Disk Cleanup, the file was deleted, but the app is not creating a new temp file as it needs it.

Comment: I allowed the WebPlus app through controlled folder access and that seems to have solved this isue.

Comment: You should turn your comment into a self answer. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://$SITEURL$/help/self-answer)